# Firebase observer during all the app life

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a firebase observer that remains alive during all the app life. What I want is to change a property of my tabBarController when some data change in firebase. Here's my code:

```
self.ref.child("mySubRef").observe(.value , with: {snapshot in

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = "!"

    })
```

So, I've tried creating it in the viewDidLoad of my first viewController and also in the viewDidAppear. I don't remove it since I want it to be there always. In the viewDidAppear it works only if I'm in that viewController at the moment of the change. If I want that change to happen no matter where  I am (always inside the tabBar) where do I have to put that code?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. The problem was that when I changed between viewControllers the reference to the observer was deallocated. So, to fix it, I have created a class like this:

```
class NotificationListener: NSObject {

let ref:FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var user:User?

func setUpListener(tabBarController:UITabBarController){

    self.user = User()
    self.ref.child("users/" + self.user!.uid + "/notifications").observe(.value , with: {snapshot in

        tabBarController.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = "!"

    })

}

}
```

Now I have a property of that class in every viewController and every one has a reference to the same object. When I change between VC it will not deallocate the object because it will still be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use Appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method but I'm not sure.

Like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("mySubRef").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //I'm not sure for this part.
        UITabBarController.init().tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = "!"
    })

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the thing is I need some info from the view controller (I need the user to be logged), is there any way to do it from the viewController?

Comment: Another way Timer method. This method repeat actions the time you specify. Look at this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-an-action-repeat-using-timer if you want to repeat actions to another controller don't call invalidate method.

Comment: Or you can directly check if user logged in the appdelegate.

Comment: I couldn't do it the way I had my app structured. Anyway, I've found the answer, thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share the answer ? Maybe I will need it :)

Comment: I did it, it's below. Is the first time I answer my question and I can't accept it until 22h have passed, but I think you can see it now :)